# How can read JSON with multiple things in sigle file java

Tags: java, json, file

I work with JSON an i came across a problem. I have JSON file like this

```
{"Text":"Here is some text","Make":"Admin","Name":"Hello"}
{"Text":"Here is some text","Make":"John","Name":"Hello"}
{"Text":"Here is some text","Make":"Admin","Name":"Hello"}
```

and I need to read from this file all text. I try but throws exception here is my code to read

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
     Object obj = null;
     try {
             obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("Project.json"));

         JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
     String name = (String) jsonObject.get("Text");
     System.out.println(name);

     }
     catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Thx for help

Comment: To make it easier for others to answer your question, you could add the relevant parts of the exception stacktrace.

Comment: I am sorry thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid JSON, It should be like this

```
[{"Text":"Here is some text","Make":"Admin","Name":"Hello"},
{"Text":"Here is some text","Make":"John","Name":"Hello"},
{"Text":"Here is some text","Make":"Admin","Name":"Hello"}]

obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("Project.json"));
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;

for (JSONObject jsonObject : jsonArray)
{
    String name = (String) jsonObject.get("Text");
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem